# Java XMLStreamReader converts &quot; to "

Tags: java, xmlstreamreader

Suppose, we have the following XML

> `<Test> 
>     <Description> &quot;Hi&quot; </Description> 
>   </Test>`

I load this XML using XMLStreamReader and parse using the reader object. When I print the characters encountered while parsing using the getText() of the reader, I see that the `&quot;` is printed as ". Although, "(double-quotes) need not have been escaped to `&quot;` in the first place, I would like to know why the parser automatically does this conversion when the escaping is not required. For instance, `&lt;, &gt; and &amp;` are preserved, without which the resulting XML would be invalid. However, this is not the case for `&quot; and &apos;`. I have to save the description the same way I receive it. Is it possible to do that with the XMLStreamReader API?

Comment: Do you need use `XMLStreamReader` to parse the XML?

Comment: @Alberto Yes, the actual XML is quite big which is why I am not using DOM

Comment: And do you get this XML or do you generate it? To prevent special characters from escaping, these data should be labeled with the special `CDATA` label

Comment: @Alberto I get this XML from a client. It is not generated locally.

Comment: With `XMLStreamReader` is not possible ignore escapes of characters. The `XMLStreamReaderImpl` class either. You would need search an implementation allow you indicate don't want escape, or use another way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have to save the description the same way I receive it.

You should not. As far as XML is concerned, `&quot;` or `"` are the exact same thing, and therefore it cannot matter to you whether you obtain one or the other.

As for why it's happening, it is an XML parser's job to unescape escaped characters so that they present you with the data they mean. It also unescapes `&lt;` and so on. However, when the text such obtained is then serialized back into XML, the serializer will escape again characters such as `<` because it's required by XML, but it won't bother escaping `"` because that's not necessary.

When you go through a process of parsing XML, then serializing again, you cannot have a concept of "preserving" the escapes as-is. That's inherently lost in conversion. The parser just is not in charge of preserving this unneeded info. However, if you wish your `"` to always be escaped to `&quot;` in the resulting XML, your XML serializer might have an option for that (you gave no details about what you're using, so I can't tell you definitely whether you can or cannot.)

Comment: I understand that the escaping is unnecessary for " and the resulting XML is totally valid. I have to satisfy a use-case which requires the data to be stores as is. The only way I knew of doing this is to ask the sender to not escape " and I needed a confirmation for that. So I guess I can just go ahead with this conclusion, right?

Comment: Nothing is impossible with computers, but if you want to preserve escaped characters you will need an XML parser that offers it, which most likely mean making one yourself, which is usually considered an unreasonable step. So yes, I'd suggest instead, either dropping the useless requirement to preserve escaped characters, or make it more irrelevant by not having characters escaped in your input document when it was unnecessary for them to be escaped.